# How to split video to 3 parts by ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, batch

I want to split video to 3 parts in batch mode. So, I have this code:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_1.mp4
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_2.mp4
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:10 D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_3.mp4
pause
```

It works but having some problem:
1. It save file: .mp4_1.mp4. How to remove ".mp4" ?
2. When filename of video contain space character. It shows error: "Invalid argument". How to fix it ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please do not ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042469/how-to-split-video-to-3-parts-by-ffmpeg) on multiple [se] sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%%~ni` instead of `%%nxi` and enclose the output filename in quotes to correctly handle filenames with spaces.